# Would a “How to make magnets” question be allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to make some homemade magnets (the stronger the better), but am not sure whether these types of questions are really welcomed on this site. Any other site's suggested if I should not post it here?

The question would be something like this:

If I want to make some strong homemade magnets to use in science experiments, what process would I follow and what materials would I need to use? Bearing in mind of course that only materials readily to the layman can be used, so not any rare earth metals etc.

Comment: The subject matter is on-topic IMO.  The only problem might be that it is a fairly broad question.  It isn't clear if you are asking about electromagnets of permanent magnets for instance.

Comment: Thanks for verifying the topicality of your question here in Meta (or in [chat]) before asking on Main when there's a degree of uncertainty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a question like this would be on topic for our site. That doesn't guarantee you'll get a good response, though. I strongly advise showing us that you've gone as far as you can go on your own before getting stuck (no pun intended) and asking for our help.

Searching for "how to make magnets" is going to get you a lot of bad results about decorating magnets that you buy from the store. Instead, try search terms like "magnetize" or "build a magnet" and spend time looking at more than just the top results. I'll tell you right now, there are so many decent resources available with those search terms, that I would expect anyone asking for our time to already have some specific details, and maybe even to have tried making some magnets already (it's not terribly difficult).

Essentially, you should approach this like it's your job, and asking a question on Stack Exchange is like asking your coworkers for help while they're working on their own stuff. If you're really stuck, that's a great time to ask, but if you ask them to help you on every little thing, they'll start to get annoyed. You can always hop into [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403/engineering) to ask little questions, including things that are too broad, subjective, off-topic, etc. on the main site.